# Digital Signature created in C# doesn't match in Java verification

Tags: java, c#, rsa, digital-signature

I need to verify the signature created from C# using "SHA1" algorithm in my JAVA program which uses "SHA1withRSA".Signature bytes are not matching. I am using Public key generated by C# program to verify signature which is stored in a file. I am new to cryptography. Below is C# code to create signature :

```
        RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

        RSA.FromXmlString(privateKey);

        var encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] originalData = encoder.GetBytes(message);
        SHA1 sha1 = SHA1.Create();

        byte[] signedBytes = RSA.SignData(originalData, sha1);

        return signedBytes;
```

I am trying to verify signature in Java program as below :

```
   //read xml file to get modulus and exponent bytes
            File publicKeyFileQA = new File(PUBLIC_KEY_FILE_QA);

            Map<String, BigInteger> publicKeyModulusExponentValues = DSXCRM_3YBP_Global_WebServicesUtil.readXMLFile(publicKeyFileQA);

            BigInteger publicKeyModulus = publicKeyModulusExponentValues.get("modulus");
            BigInteger publicKeyExponent = publicKeyModulusExponentValues.get("exponent");

            System.out.println("BigInteger Modulus : "+ publicKeyModulus + "BigInteger Exponent : " + publicKeyExponent);

            String messageWithSignature = (String) mapDataToPost.get("SignedMessage");
            String encryptedMessage = (String) mapDataToPost.get("EncryptedMessage");

            byte[] signatureBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(messageWithSignature);

            System.out.println("Signature bytes : "+ new String(signatureBytes));


            byte[] cipherMessage = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(encryptedMessage);

            System.out.println("Cipher Message : "+ new String(cipherMessage));

            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
            RSAPublicKeySpec publicKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(publicKeyModulus, publicKeyExponent);
            PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
            Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
            sig.initVerify(publicKey); //public key of sender
            sig.update(cipherMessage);

            boolean isRightSender = sig.verify(signatureBytes);
            System.out.println("isRightSender : "+isRightSender);
```

but result to match signature is false. I am not getting what is wrong. Can you please provide any suggestions. Is there any other algorithm which is compatible to both C# and JAVA to have same Signatures? Thanks!

Comment: I see no apparent errors in your code. May be the encoding of the message and signature bytes sent from C# to Java?

Comment: yes, i agree with you. it may be some encoding issue i am facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading a field called "SignedMessage", storing that in a variable called "messageWithSignature" and then treating it as if it were just the signature.  What data is actually present in that blob?

You're further printing binary data as if it were text (via `new String(byte[])`). You should print Base64 or hex on both sides to see if they match, for both the message bytes (which appear to be called `cipherMessage` in your verifier) and the signature.

If you switch to static data (to avoid things like counting newlines on read) then it should be valid to do

```
byte[] originalData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("This is a static message test.");
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(rsa.SignData(originalData), "SHA1"));
```

then take that output, put it into your Java program and verify

```
byte[] originalData = "This is a static message test.".getBytes("UTF-8");
byte[] signature = Base64.getDecoder().decode(theOutputFromTheCSharpProgram);
Signature verifier = new Signature("SHA1withRSA");
verifier.initVerify(publicKey);
verifier.update(originalData);
System.out.println(verifier.verify(signature));
```

If that part doesn't work, then you must not be faithfully representing the same key on both sides.

The binary format of the signatures for RSA are the same in C# and Java; so once you get data transport lined up well everything should work.

Comment: I tried above part, issue is after parsing base64 string into byte[] in java it is not same as we get from C#. I am using DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(messageWithSignature);

Comment: I got this right direction that i need to use base64 string only to get from C# to java into byte[] as no other format would be compatible between C# and java, I am accepting your answer. Yet I have some difficulties that signature doesn't match.

Comment: @Coder Are you sure you're building `publicKey` correctly? In particular, BigInteger is likely to interpret anything with the high bit set as a negative number.  Check if it tests as less than BigInteger.zero

Comment: Yes, because when C# program uses Public key generated by Java program to encrypt data and Private key to decrypt data, it works fine. So ideally signature should also match.